# how to fetch data from database in joomla 2.5

Tags: database, joomla, joomla2.5

I just tried this code but i didn't get output. anyone correct my code

```
 $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT * from #__virtuemart_manufacturers";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $itemrow = $rows[0];
    $on_frontpage = $itemrow->content_id;
    print_r($on_frontpage);
```

i didn't want for the MVC.. just send me the simple method to fetch the data

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT * from #__virtuemart_manufacturers";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
echo $value->content_id;
}
```

ObjectList means the result return as object array you have to iterate with foreach.
Also loadAssocList() with associate array.

Hope it  may helps..

Answer (score 2):

The code for the database query is correct.
The problem is that Virtuemart doesn't have a `content_id` column in the `#__virtuemart_manufacturers` table. Thus the property doesn't exists and you don't get a result with `print_r`.

Turning on error logging should tell you that as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to fix this is

1. Try running the SQL in the PHPMyAdmin and see whether your query is correct.
2. `print_r($rows)` and see whether you get the result.